# Under what conditions does matrix multiplication commute?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is just a check on my reasoning, I guess.

So for two matrices $A, B$ to commute, the following must hold:

$$(AB)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}b_{kj} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}b_{ik}a_{kj} = (BA)_{ij}$$

This can happen if for all $i, j, k$:

a. $a_{ik}=a_{kj}$ and $b_{ik}=b_{kj}$, or

b. $a_{ik}=b_{ik}$ and $a_{kj}=b_{kj}$, i.e. $A=B$, or

c. $a_{ik} = 0$ or $b_{ik} = 0$, i.e. either matrix is null.

Are there more possibilities?

Edit: I originally had (a) as "Both matrices are symmetric", but as @user1551 points out, this is not true. After fixing the summations, I see where I was mistaken. I'm not sure how to characterize (a) now.

Comment: Certainly any power of $A$ commutes with $A$ for any matrix $A$.

Comment: Your case (a) is not true. $A,B$ may not commute if they are symmetric. Consider, e.g., $A$ is the matrix whose only nonzero entry is the $(1,1)$-th one and $B$ is the all-one matrix. By the way, I don't understand what the symbol $\sum_k^j$ means.

Comment: @user1551

Hm. 

The summation is supposed to capture that each entry is the inner product of a row of A and a column of B (or the other way around).

Comment: Then it should be $\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_{ik}b_{kj}$, not $...a_{ik}b_{ki}$

Comment: @IvanNeretin Oh ok. I see where I messed up then. Thanks! I didn't know about \limit. I've always just written it the other way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two matrices commute when they are [simultaneously triangularisable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Simultaneous_triangularisability), i.e., when there is some basis in which they are both triangular. Roughly speaking, it is when they have the same [eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors), probably with different eigenvalues. (But then there are degenerate cases, which make it all more complicated.)

This property has really nothing to do with A and B being symmetric. Indeed, there are examples of matrices which are symmetric and don't commute...
$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}2& 1\\1 & 3 \end{matrix}\right),\;
B=\left(\begin{matrix}3& 1\\1 & 2 \end{matrix}\right),
$$
...and those which are not symmetric but do commute:
$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}1& 1\\0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right),\;
B=\left(\begin{matrix}1& 2\\0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right).
$$

Comment: Can I ask what are the degenerate cases? Specifically, is it true that any two matrices commute iff they have the same eigenspaces (excluding with eigenvalue $1$)? The backward implication is clear, but what about the forward implication?

Comment: How's having the same eigenspaces is different from having the same eigenvectors, and what's so special about the eigenvalue 1? Degenerate cases are the defective matrices; I'm not quite sure about their behavior in this regard, but they do have a certain kind of "criminal record" for being exceptions to pretty much _anything_.

Comment: The reason I singled out the eigenvalue $1$ is because a rotation about an axis commutes with a stretch along the same axis but their eigenspaces differ by those for eigenvalue $1$, and I had forgotten where I saw some Math SE post about this phenomenon. Now I recall I saw it at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2019710, which makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Yeah, that answer is good. Still, note that it applies to rotations, which are but a subset of all matrices. In general, you don't necessarily have those complex eigenvalues, nor are you guaranteed to have that eigenvalue 1.

Comment: Hmm so do you have a concrete example of a degenerate case? My first comment is clearly a wrong guess because two orthogonal stretches in 3d commute but don't share eigenspaces, and would presumably be a degenerate case? I was just curious to know what is the simplest 'geometric' characterization, since I can't visualize the meaning of "triangularizable".

Comment: No, I don't; I just said that I'm not sure. Well, let's look at your orthogonal stretches, one that changes x, but leaves y and z as they were, and another that stretches z. The eigenvectors of the first one would be (1,0,0) and two _any_ vectors orthogonal to it; those of the second are (0,0,1) and two any vectors orthogonal to it. Doesn't look very similar; still, by choosing from those "any", we **may select** a complete set of three eigenvectors which would be common for both matrices. That's a geometric characterization for you.

Comment: But what is the meaning of "complete set"? A 3d rotation has only one physical eigenvector but it has a 2-dimensional eigenspace, and we can't just pick 2 from it, otherwise your criterion would imply that two orthogonal rotations commute.

Comment: OK, now I see... You're referring to a plane as an eigenspace of a 3D rotation, because (correct me if I'm wrong) the rotation keeps the plane where it was. Wikipedia uses a [different definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Eigenspaces.2C_geometric_multiplicity.2C_and_the_eigenbasis_for_matrices); according to it, we have two distinct complex eigenvalues with corresponding complex eigenvectors, and no 2D eigenspace.

Comment: Oh oops I guess what I was talking about is called "invariant subspace", but I've forgotten much of the little linear algebra that I learnt a long time ago... I can't visualize complex eigenvectors either haha..

Comment: The matrices $\begin{pmatrix} 1& 1 & 0 \\ 0& 1& 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0 & 0 \\ 0& 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ don't commute despite being simultaneously triangularisable. So, being simultaneously triangularisable is necessary, but by far not sufficient.